# IE7 syntax error for if(...) return false

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

One of our advertisers has a landing page that contains the following Javascript function:

```
sfHover = function() {
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
    var sfEls1 = document.getElementById("catmenu").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls1.length; i++) {
        sfEls1[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover1";
        }
        sfEls1[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover1\\b"), "");
        }
    }
        var sfEls1 = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls1.length; i++) {
        sfEls1[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        }
        sfEls1[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
```

When going to the page in IE7, it reports a syntax error on the `if` line. As far as I can tell, it's perfectly fine syntax; IE8 doesn't complain, nor does Chrome. The only potential issue I can see is that the `return false;` statement isn't in curly braces, but they're optional; I tried adding them, and it didn't resolve the error.

Is this a bug in IE7?

UPDATE:

I removed everything but this function definition from the page, to ensure that it's not related to one of the many other scripts that it loads. The error still occurred.

I removed everything but the `if` line, the error went away. I added back the next line, the error returned. The interesting thing is that the second line gets an expected error: there's no `catmenu` element on the page (even before I removed all the HTML), so it correctly complains that `document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object`. I've asked our marketing person to let the advertiser know about this problem.

So could this logic error be causing IE7 to think there's a syntax error on the preceding line? I added a `catmenu` element to the page, and the syntax error went away as well.

Then I added back the rest of the function. The second `sfEls1` assignment also references a nonexistent ID. This caused it to report the preceding `}` line as a syntax error! I think that confirms that this is a weird IE7 bug.

Comment: What error is IE7 giving you?

Comment: IE7 is notoriously bad at reporting errors. Try getting the script through JSLint. I didn't see a syntax error in this snippet.

Comment: It just says "Syntax error".

Comment: The code seems correct. Have you copy-pasted it? Sometimes a code copied from a web site contains non-printing characters causing syntax errors (especially code copied from jsFiddle). Also Frits is right, IE can report an error even occuring in the wrong file.

Comment: Have you tried removing everything else but the faulty `if`? Does it still produces an error?

Comment: See my update. It looks like this is just an IE7 error reporting bug: an invalid object error on one line causes it to also report a syntax error on the preceding line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an error reporting bug in IE7. When it reports the error:

```
'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
```

because `getElementById()` doesn't find the ID on the page, it also reports an extraneous syntax error on the line preceding this.

So there *is* an error in the function, just not the syntax error that this error message is complaining about. MS appears to have fixed this error reporting bug in IE8 -- Compatibility Mode doesn't even replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you declare the variable `sfEls1` twice.

Comment: I don't think that should be a problem !

Comment: Hogan.. If you re-declare variable in some other languages `- result will be undefined, or NaN`, but not in javascript.

Comment: It is not recommended to redeclare the variable use the `var` keyword.. But that should not cause the syntax error

Comment: @Sushanth-- Remember this is IE7, a version of javascript that was "questionable".  Should and does are miles apart in IE7.  The OP should try a name change and see what happens.

Comment: Hogan .. I tested it out using a fiddle and seems to be working fine on IE7

Comment: @Sushanth-- So you don't get the error at all?  Might be a plugin only on the OP's install then.

Comment: I removed the second `var` declaration, it doesn't fix it. See my question update.